# How to recursively resolve types?

Tags: typescript

Having some problems with the following type definitions.

```
type Check<T> = (value: any) => value is T;

type Static<T> = T extends Check<infer U> ? U : never;

type Interface<T extends { [index: string]: Check<any> }> = Check<{ [P in keyof T]: Static<T[P]> }>;

type IPlayer = Static<
    Interface<{
        name: Check<string>;
        data: Interface<{
            score: Check<number>;
        }>;
    }>
>;
```

With TypeScript 3.1.1, if I hover over `IPlayer` in VS Code, it resolves the type as:

```
type IPlayer = {
    name: string;
    data: any;
}
```

However, I'd like it to resolve to:

```
type IPlayer = {
    name: string;
    data: {
        score: number;
    };
}
```

How do I change my type definitions to make this work?

Comment: Looks like a glitch in VS Code, since typechecking is correct - `{name: "name", data: "data"}` can't be assigned to `IPlayer`. Furthermore, `type IPlayerData = IPlayer['data']` resolves just as needed. I don't know how to make a full answer out of this, sorry.

Comment: Thanks @Cerberus . Do you know if this should be reported as a VSCode or a TypeScript issue?

Comment: It's a TypeScript issue because the IntelliSense is generated by TypeScript.  There is already [Microsoft/TypeScript#14041](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14041) but it's closed as "Design Limitation" and currently locked so you can't comment on it. Not sure if there's a newer one, or if you have anything new to add that warrants a new issue (but pls link to the old one if you do create a new issue)